# Click button to add value Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im working on spring MVC webApp project and I'm sort of stuck at this one step. I have a JSP page that have buttons with value of $1.00 .25 etc. when user click the buttons the value need to be stored for purchase. i have a method in the controller but unsure what to pass in the parameter for the input. Please point me to the right the direction. thanks.

```
    <div class="form-group" >
     <input  class="form-control" style="text-align: center" id="display-money" placeholder="Enter Money" required/> <!--to diplay total -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <button method="POST" 
              action="addOne-btn"
              value="addOne"
              modelAttribute="add-one" 
              type="button"
              name="one"
              id="addOne" 
              class="btn btn-default ">
               Add Dollar
               </button>
            </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <button method="POST"
   value="addQrtr"    
   action="addQrtr-btn"
   type="button"
   name="qrtr"
   id="addQRTR"  
   class="btn btn-default">
   Add Quarter
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     //controller
     @RequestMapping(value = "/money", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String money(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
      BigDecimal moneyIn = new BigDecimal(0);
      String input = request.getParameter();//pass in onlcick from jsp. 
       if(input.equals("addOne")){
           moneyIn.add(new BigDecimal(1.00));
       }

        if(input.equals("")){
           moneyIn.add(new BigDecimal(.25));
       }

     }
```

Comment: Use model.asMap or use @modelattribute in the params of your function. See http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @ModelAttribute in your submit controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/money", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String money(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute Bean bean){
  BigDecimal moneyIn = new BigDecimal(0);
  String input = bean.get***();//pass in onlcick from jsp. 
  if(input.equals("addOne")){
       moneyIn.add(new BigDecimal(1.00));
  }

  if(input.equals("")){
      moneyIn.add(new BigDecimal(.25));
  }
}
```